# GTest in VS2010 and .exe - different results

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, exe, googletest

I have a VS2010 solution with a code project and a 'UnitTest' project. The code project is compiled to a dll (and generating a .lib). The UnitTest project is compiled to a .exe.

In the code, I have a method `mymethod()` which should be covered by one unittest. If i set 'UnitTest' as the startup project and run, i can see that `mymethod()` is called indeed:

- with breakpoint into it in Release mode with disabled optimization + in Debug mode
- adding printf into `mymethod()`, printf is called

The UnitTest is compiled to a .exe properly, the .lib and .dll are up to date.

When I launch the .exe from the file, the printf is not called (whereas other printf at other points in the code are called). If i launch it from command line, same thing.

It is sure that another path is taken in the code when UnitTest called from the .exe.

What important things should be checked ?

What can be happening here ?

### ---------------------------

EDIT

After investigation: a flag is set to 0 when test is launched with executable, because **a conversion to double fails**: i printf the following

```
printf("arr_size[0] %d, arr_size[1] %d, numOffElms %d 
-- result multiplication REAL %d, 
NOT REAL %d",arr_size[0], arr_size[1],numOffElms, 
(real_T)(arr_size[0] * arr_size[1]), arr_size[0] * arr_size[1]);
```

where `REAL_T` is a macro for `double` defined with

`typedef double real_T;`

printed result is the following

```
arr_size[0] 90000, arr_size[1] 24, numOffElms 0 -- result multiplication REAL 0, 
NOT REAL 2160000
```

!!!!

**It appears that in VS2010, in Debug or Release with disabled Optimization, the conversion to double is correct.**

Where does this come from and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `the former compiled to a dll and the former compiled to a .exe`, can you fix this sentence please?

Comment: done i just fixed this sentence any idea?

Comment: @MarcoA. I also edited with more details, do you have a clue?

Comment: Are you getting the error only when you print the multiplication results with the `printf` commands indicated?